# .gitlab-ci.yml error: "apk: command not found"

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following ***.gitlab-ci.yml*** file:

```
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apk add --update -y python-pip
    - pip install docker-compose
  script:
    - echo "Testing the app"
    - docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
    - production
    - feature/deploy-debug-gitlab
  before_script:
    - apk add --update -y python-pip
    - pip install docker-compose
  script:
    - echo "Building the app"
    - docker-compose build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
    - develop
    - feature/deploy
    - feature/deploy-debug-gitlab
  before_script:
    - apk add --update -y python-pip
    - pip install docker-compose
  script:
    - echo "Deploying the app"
    - docker-compose up -d
  environment: production
  when: manual
```

When the Gitlab runner executes it, I get the following error:

```
$ apk add --update -y python-pip
bash: line 82: apk: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

How am I supposed to install apk? Or what image other than `docker` should I be using to run this `gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it turns out I had two different runners: one marked as "shell executor" (Ubuntu) and the other marked as "docker executor“.

This error was being thrown out only when the Ubuntu runner was dispatching the job, since Ubuntu doesn´t come with apk.

I disabled the Ubuntu runner and solved the problem.

Comment: Did you have to setup a custom GitLab runner for this, I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is to set your installation on step *above* test, as in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3221)

```
image: docker:latest

services:
- docker:dind

before_script:
- apk add --update python-pip
```

Comment: Thank you @VonC, but that alternative is giving me the same error: "apk command not found". Actually, I've realized that the task fails randomly. Most often it fails with that error, but some times it passes succesfully. I have to click on "Retry" until it passes. I'm really confused.

Comment: Strange indeed, some kind of network connection issue, perhaps?

Comment: @Jaumzera Is it a runner issue? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56392255/6309)