# apk command not found in Gitlab ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd

I'm trying to run a simple apk command in my gitlab-ci.yml file, but it throws the following error:

```
$ apk add --no-cache py3-pip
/scripts-28331433-1624151765/step_script: line 166: apk: command not found
```

It looks like this error is possible if the runner is Ubuntu based, but I'm not sure how to configure the runners for my pipeline (or force docker runners for my runs).
Any ideas or should I keep retrying until it passes?

Comment: Apk is the package installer for Alpine Linux. Have you tried using `apt-get install -y python3-pip` instead?

Answer (score -1):

> It looks like this error is possible if the runner is Ubuntu based

That is [confirmed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484059/6309).

Having a [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) should mean, using a docker-in-docker:

```sh
image: docker:latest

services:
- docker:dind

before_script:
- apk add --no-cache py3-pip
```